# .htacces - how to use

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been looking around on the internet on how to use an .htacces file. But i just can't get my head around it.
I'm trying to rewrite the url so I can easily explode it with php and make sites in OOP.
Also, do I need to change it when programming on a localhost and online?

Thanks in advance

Edit 1:

I would use the "params" to get the url and explode it in different pieces to build a page. For example, the first param would be the language, second would be the page then the action (delete an item, add an item,...)

For the moment i'm working on a localhost. The url is localhost/testsite/index.php

The code i have now is the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Do you have any specific issue?

Comment: What's the URL you want to rewrite?  What do you want to change it to?  We're here to answer *specific* problems, not give you a full tutorial.

Comment: `The url is localhost/testsite/index.php` ... which kind of negates the entire purpose of building a RESTful rewrite really. Also your rewrite won't actually do anything there because `index.php` actually exists (presumably) so it'll be skipped by the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition. I'd suggest looking at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: The correct name of the file is `.htaccess` (with two "S" at the end). You misspelled it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, and simple if you were to rewrite

`www.site.com/news.php?id=123` to
 `www.site.com/this_is_news_title`

You should create a file called `.htaccess` and put it inside your htdocs folder and write in it the following

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/.*$ /news.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Try it and play around with it.